# Resource created as many times as accumulated requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a really weird bug. I have a very simple Rails 4.2 app, and I was just starting to add some JavaScript functionality. I've started by adding a `remote: true` option to a form, but after that more than one resource are created in the database. It seems to have a criteria, though, and it is that the number of resources created equals the total amount of pages visited since the server started. So:

`rails s` and refresh the `/new` page, will create 1 resource.

Now visit page 1, page 2, page 3, and go back to `/new` and submit, and 4 resources are created.

Now visit page 5, page 6, go back to `/new` and submit and 7 resources are created.

As I have mentioned, I was just starting with JS, and only had another script that is not related with this in anyway (bug still happens if I remove this file and restart the server).

Just for reference, I've created a new Rails app and put `remote: true` to the form and, obviously, this is not happening, so something there is messing up my app.

I don't even know how to research this. Any clue on where should I start looking at?

EDIT: I've tried to reproduce the same situation in tests, using Capybara and doing several page visits before filling up a form, and I couldn't.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**layouts/application.html.erb**

Moved it to the end of file and added `cache: true`

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, cache: true %>
</body>
</html>
```

Again: there was only one script in the app, and I've removed it. There are no more JS thing anywhere. None, at all.

I think the relevant question here is: **how on earth can the number of page visits since the server was started be related to the number of resources created?**

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to post some code to help us get our heads around it? Seeing things like your JavaScript, controller, JS manifest, etc. can help. One thing to check, it burned me once in a team setting, was I had `remote: true` on a form but another team member had added an `onclick` event to a button in a form that submitted via a jQuery method. So my form was double-submitted.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky Sure! But I think there's nothing special there. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I think the most helpful thing to post would be the contents of your new view and controller action because you say visiting `/new` causes the problem.

Comment: Can you post the remote form? And part of `routes.rb`? It sounds like you have a POST route to /new or something.

Comment: Here they go. But trust me, nothing special there. I'm starting to think that this will either be an obscure bug somewhere, or the most stupid and obvious thing ever.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky Thank you. Finally found what the problem was. Check the answer if interested.

Comment: @ptd Thank you. Finally found what the problem was. Check the answer if interested.

Comment: @jpriebe Thank you. Finally found what the problem was. Check the answer if interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't yet believe it. It all was because of this:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, cache: true %>
</body>
</html>
```

I had to place the javascript tag *back* to its original place, within the `<head>` tag.

```
<head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, cache: true %>
</head>
```

Don't ask me why, but placing the javascript file at the bottom of the file caused all this mess.

EDIT:

Turns out this is something related with Turbolinks. **Removing Turbolinks fixes the issue, and I can load all JS at the end of the document, again.** See [this](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/153#issuecomment-13637290) issue on Turbolinks, and also [this](https://github.com/robertlandreaux/Gradejoy/issues/24) on someone's project.